# How do I turn off package start and package end from my custom log provider?

Tags: logging, ssis

In my SSIS package, I created a custom log provider that appends all my logs into an html file.  In the logging details, i selected ONLY errors and warnings to be logged.  However, i am getting the Start and End Package log entries as well.  This defeats the purpose of being able to see errors only when they happen.  Any suggestions?

I am running SQL 2008 R2.  I read an article online that suggests to make an edit in the registry, but this seems to have only turned off logging for Start and End events in the Windows event logs, not in mine.

Comment: That is a really good idea.  I am not really seeing a better solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An alternate option would be that you can log the errors to SQL Server database instead of using custom log provider. That way you can write simple queries to filter the data based on what you would like to view.